# An aperiodic hexagonal tile?

Tags: tiling

This hexagon-with-dents is a tile which, I think, tiles the plane in a necessarily aperiodic way:

```
     ________  __ 
    /        \/  \__
   _\              /
  /                \
 /                  \
/                    \
\                    /
 \                  _\
  \                /
  /_              /
    \_/\_________/
```

This is essentially the [Socolar–Taylor tile](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.4279.pdf).
I'm rather surprised that this tile does not appear in the paper of Socolar and Taylor,
and that it also doesn't appear in Wikipedia's [list of aperiodic sets of tiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aperiodic_sets_of_tiles).

Did I miss something?
Am I maybe wrong to claim that this tile tiles the plane in a necessarily aperiodic way?

**Question:** Does the above tile tile the plane in a necessarily aperiodic way?

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not a hexagonal tile. The dents and extrusions count as additional sides, so the tile would be called 24-gonal.

Comment: Well, you don't give us a proof of aperiodicity, or say how it is related to the Socolar–Taylor tile.  Are the dents supposed to enforce the matching rules prescribed by the decorations in Figure 1?

Comment: @Algernon. Yes. The black lines in Figure 1 of the Socolar-Taylor paper can be consistently oriented (so that all black triangles of varying sizes run conterclockwise). The dents in my tile mark to location where the black lines of Socolar-Taylor meet the boundary of the hexagon. [Oscar Lanzi: you're absolutely correct]

Comment: But Socolar-Taylor also need the reflection of their tile in order to tile the entire plane.  If you introduce an orientation for each black triangle, then the reflection of your tile would have opposite orientations and things may not fit together.

Comment: @Algernon Take the Socolar-Taylor tile. Forget all the Magenta decorations. Then it's equal to its mirror image. I think that this simpler Socolar-Taylor tile (with only the back lines as decorations) is already constrained enough to imply that it tiles the plane in a necessarily aperiodic way.

Comment: @AndréHenriques: In order to be aperiodic, your tile has to (1) tile the entire plane but (2) only in non-periodic way.  Your tile is not invariant under reflection.  My point was that with the additional *orientation* information imposed, it is not clear that your tile can tile the entire plane at all.  Of course your last claim that the magenta decorations are not needed to enforce non-periodicity also needs a proof.

Comment: @Algernon There's no need to argue: check Ville Salo's solution.

Comment: @AndréHenriques: I was just pointing out the loopholes in your (non-existent) argument.  Wasn't that the reason you posted your question?

Comment: Cool use of ASCII art!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This seems to admit periodic tilings, so there is probably some problem. [image: periodic]. Numbers are rotation amounts.

Comment: There's no problem. You have found a periodic tiling.

Comment: I just meant, problem with the Socolar-Taylor connection.